# Durable Function doesn't seem to be running Activity Functions in parallel

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a `Durable Function App` (.NET 7 Isolated Worker) where I'm running a foreach loop in the `Orchestrator` to have activity functions run in parallel in the following way:

```
 foreach (var item in itemList)
 {
     itemIndex++; //sent to activity function to determine if a new file needs to be created as we're storing results in blob storage
     activities.Add(context.CallActivityAsync(Constants.FUNCTION_NAME, new activityInput
     {
         activityInput data
     }));
 }

await Task.WhenAll(activities);
```

The completion of each activity function takes about 3 minutes (lots of business logic/DB access). As I continue to stress test the function and add more instances, the time to run increases linearly with however many Activity Functions are running. So, for a fan out of 10 functions, it takes roughly 30 minutes. This doesn't seem to be running in parallel based on the time it's taking to run (or maybe it is running in parallel but is so load-intensive it slows down)?

Is there something I'm missing or need to look for in the business logic of the activity function that could be halting the individual instances (like DB calls, other things)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have set any concurrency limits for your Durable Function. In some cases it can cause activities to run sequentially instead of in parallel. Ensure that your host.json or function.json settings allow for sufficient concurrency.

High resource utilization on your worker instances can slow down parallel execution.

Can you check using Azure Monitor and Application Insights to gather more insights into the performance of your Durable Function and especially its dependencies. This can provide valuable metrics and traces to diagnose the issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#configuration-of-throttles

Comment: I'll definitely check that out. There was nothing in the host.json/function.json to indicate maxConcurrentActivityFunctions limits (or same for orchestrator) but I can double check. And I'm trying to add more telemetry to the Function App to get the SQL commands called and whatever else may be causing performance bottlenecks as some instances take 6+ minutes to run. Thank you for the insight, this should provide a good starting point to figure out the issue!

Comment: How can I check resource utilization on worker instances? Is that something that should be queryable in Azure? Like, looking at individual activity function instances and what utilization it had? If this is needs to be in a separate question, I can do that.

Comment: Under metrics section, You can select the specific function within your Function App if you only want metrics for that function.